# Why the same result both DES Encrypt and DESede Encrypt?

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption, des

I'm try to be compatible Encrypt/Decrypt both C# and Java.

As I know the default mode is 'ecb/pkcs5' in Java, and 'cbc/pkcs7' in C#.

So I match these things.

**1st question is that PKCS7 and PKCS5 are compatible each other??**,

there is no PKCS7 in Java so I use PKCS5. but I can get same encrypted data [even the padding-way is different ,pkcs7/pkcs5,] Is it possible? or these are compatible?

**2nd question is that Why I get same result even though the mode, way are all different?**

I compare 'DES-ECB / DES-CBC / TripleDES-ECB' these things. and C# is working well, results are all different.

Input > HELLO Output > (ECB)/dZf3gUY150=  (CBC) V17s5QLzynM= (Triple)sWGS0GMe1jE

but I get same reulst in Java ..

Input > HELLO Output > (ECB)/dZf3gUY150= (CBC)/dZf3gUY150= (Triple)/dZf3gUY150=

When debugging the flow is right.

Here is my code.

**C#**

```
public static string Encrypt_DES(string originalString, byte[] key, string mode)
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        if (mode.Equals("ECB"))
            cryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        else if (mode.Equals("CBC"))
        {
            cryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            cryptoProvider.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        }

        cryptoProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(key, key), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
        writer.Write(originalString);
        writer.Flush();
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        writer.Flush();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
    }

public static string Encrypt_TripleDES(string source, string key)
    {
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashMD5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        byte[] byteHash;
        byte[] byteBuff;

        byteHash = hashMD5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        desCryptoProvider.Key = byteHash;
        desCryptoProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; //CBC, CFB
        desCryptoProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        byteBuff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);

        string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(desCryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteBuff, 0, byteBuff.Length));
        return encoded;
    }
```

**Java(Android)**

```
public String Encrypt(String str, String desKey, String mode) {
    try {
        KeySpec keySpec = null;
        SecretKey key = null;
        Cipher ecipher = null;
        if (desKey.length() == 8) {
            keySpec = new DESKeySpec(desKey.getBytes("UTF8"));
            key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(keySpec);
            if(mode.equals(ECB)){
                ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
                ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            }else if (mode.equals(CBC)){
                ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
                ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,ivSpec);
            }
        } else if (desKey.length() == 24) {
            keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(desKey.getBytes("UTF8"));
            key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede").generateSecret(keySpec);
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        }

        byte[] data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] crypt = ecipher.doFinal(data);

        return Base64.encodeToString(crypt, 0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("ZVM", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

- As I understand 'IV' is for CBC, When making password, it is mixed with IV(not the key but like key). Is it right?

Thanks.

Comment: Your first question is answered [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/13022) (they are the same). The second question is unclear, because you haven't shown the code for that. Perhaps you forgot to specify the IV, which is a randomizer. The same IV needs to be used during decryption, but it is not secret. I have no idea what you're asking in your third question. DES and Triple DES are different if you're not using the same three subkeys in 3DES.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clearer. Example inputs and outputs would help greatly.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for your answer first. and I edited quite many contents.  and as I understand your link, there is no compatible both PKCS5 and 7... right?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I added 'IV' for CBC then face other error.  I think 'IV' is necessary value for using CBC mode.  but I don't know what i miss in other way (except ECB)... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PKCS7 and PKCS5 are compatible each other

PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 paddings are compatible (equal) for DES. For AES, Java actually uses PKCS#7 padding even though you would write `AES/xyz/PKCS5Padding`.

> Why I get same result even though the mode, way are all different?

First, let's see how Java behaves. The ciphertexts for DES-ECB, DES-CBC and DESede-ECB are all equal. This is correct **if**

1. the key is the same (DES supports only 8 byte keys, but Triple DES supports 8, 16 and 24 byte keys where non-24 byte keys are expanded to 24 byte keys),
2. the plaintext is the same,
3. the plaintext is less than 8 bytes long (block size of DES/Triple DES) and
4. the IV is an all 0x00 bytes IV.

Those are all true in the Java code. If you have trouble grasping that, combine the encryption routines for the [ECB and CBC modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).

The result of Triple DES might be a bit confusing. I *assume* that you've taken your 8 byte key for DES and replicated it either twice or thrice for use in Triple DES. This is an issue, because Triple DES encryption consists of three steps of normal DES: EDE means Encryption + Decryption + Encryption. If all the three subkeys are the same, the one of the Encryption steps cancels out with the Decryption step and the whole thing is equivalent to a single DES encryption.

Let's see why C# behaves differently:

The ciphertext from DES-CBC is different from DES-ECB, because the IV is not an all 0x00 bytes IV. `cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(key, key)` creates an Encryptor with the IV set to `key` (the second argument). That's not what you want. Just use `cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor()` instead.

The ciphertext from DESede-ECB is different from DES-ECB, because you're running the key through a hash function. The key is therefore different.

---

**Don't use DES nowadays.** It only provides 56 bit of security. AES would be a much better, because it's more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

Comment: Wow... Thanks your answer! I can guess what I miss. and can I ask you one more thing? As your answer, I use same key, plaintext, and Iv. these are the reason why the all ways(DES-ECB, DES-CBC, DESede-ECB) are equall. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, and your plaintext is shorter than 8 bytes, because ECB is the same as CBC for the first block.

Comment: Yep! I got it... you saved my time!! really real Thanks to your answer! Thanks.